# Why is EEVEE GPU rendering producing glitches?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, gpu

I'm using a geforce rtx 2080 super and am getting weird glitches in my renders. Does it have to do with the gpu driver?

[image]

Comment: Hello, please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/205859/edit) your [original question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205859/why-are-my-gpu-renders-showing-glitches-in-eevee-nvidia-rtx-2080-super) instead creating a duplicate post. Please read [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) also to see what to do when you don't receive an  answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my GPU renders showing glitches in EEVEE? Nvidia RTX 2080 Super](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205859/why-are-my-gpu-renders-showing-glitches-in-eevee-nvidia-rtx-2080-super)